# Why does this downscaling algorithm produce artifacts?

Tags: c++, c++11, cocos2d-x, cocos2d-x-3.0, cocos2d-x-3.x

I have a scaling algorithm which appears to scale the image to the right size, but produces artefacts(slight image corruption) in the right half of the image. As I am inexperienced using pointers, I suspect I may have blundered with my pointer arithmetic!

To run the project on OSX:
1. Download from :https://www.dropbox.com/s/myme1z1mkxjwyjf/artifact.zip?dl=0

2. Open the xcodeproj file found in proj.ios
3. All code that is of relevance, is in HelloWorldScene.cpp

In function test(), you can comment out / uncomment the method we wish to test.:

```
void HelloWorld::test(){
    testCopy(); //In this case the image appears as expected. (a simple copy)
//    testScale(); //In this case there are strange artifacts on the right tip of the arrow.
}
```

Test copy, is my attempt at just copying the contents of the buffer without doing anything bad like memory corruption, leaking etc... The image appears on the screen looking ok!

```
void HelloWorld::testCopy(){
std::string infile = _imageName;

Image* img = new Image();
img->initWithImageFile(infile);
auto odata = img->getData();

Image* copy = new Image();

int components = 4;
auto finalDataLen = img->getDataLen();
auto finalData = static_cast<unsigned char*>(malloc(finalDataLen));

for (int i = 0; i<img->getWidth(); i++) {
    for (int j = 0; j<img->getHeight(); j++) {
        unsigned char *pixel = odata + (i + j * img->getWidth()) * components;

        unsigned char *fpixel = finalData + (i + j * img->getWidth()) * components;
        fpixel[0] = pixel[0];
        fpixel[1] = pixel[1];
        fpixel[2] = pixel[2];
        fpixel[3] = pixel[3];
    }
}
copy->initWithRawData(finalData, finalDataLen, img->getWidth(), img->getHeight(), 8);
Texture2D* tk = new Texture2D();
tk->initWithImage(copy);

Sprite* foo = Sprite::createWithTexture(tk);
foo->setPosition(Director::getInstance()->getVisibleSize().width/2,Director::getInstance()->getVisibleSize().height/2);
foo->setScale(0.8);
this->addChild(foo);

delete img;
delete copy;
return;
```

}

Now comment out testCopy(); and uncomment testScale(); In this case the image appears but with some corruption the right side of the image!

```
void HelloWorld::testScale(){
    std::string infile = _imageName;

    Image* img = new Image();
    img->initWithImageFile(infile);
    Image* scl = new Image();
    scaleImage(img, scl, 0.8);

    Texture2D* tk = new Texture2D(); //Texture is needed as long as the sprite exists, so we aren't deleting it.
    tk->initWithImage(scl);
    Sprite* foo = Sprite::createWithTexture(tk);
    foo->setPosition(Director::getInstance()->getVisibleSize().width/2,Director::getInstance()->getVisibleSize().height/2);
    this->addChild(foo);

    delete img;
    delete scl;

    return;
}

void HelloWorld::scaleImage(Image* original,Image* scaledImage,const float& scale){
    int width = scale*original->getWidth();
    int height = scale*original->getHeight();

    int x=4;

    unsigned char* data = original->getData();

    auto dataLen = width * height * x * sizeof(unsigned char);
    auto data2 = static_cast<unsigned char*>(malloc(dataLen));

    //sprshrink seems to be the problem method.
    sprshrink(data2, width, height, data, original->getWidth(), original->getHeight());
    scaledImage->initWithRawData(data2, dataLen, width, height, 8);
}

//Why does this method produce artifcats ?
void HelloWorld::sprshrink(unsigned char *dest, int dwidth, int dheight, unsigned char *src, int swidth, int sheight){
    int x, y;
    int i, ii;
    float red, green, blue, alpha;
    float xfrag, yfrag, xfrag2, yfrag2;
    float xt, yt, dx, dy;
    int xi, yi;


    dx = ((float)swidth)/dwidth;
    dy = ((float)sheight)/dheight;

    for(yt= 0, y=0;y<dheight;y++, yt += dy)
    {
        yfrag = (float) ceil(yt) - yt;
        if(yfrag == 0)
            yfrag = 1;
        yfrag2 = yt+dy - (float) floor(yt + dy);
        if(yfrag2 == 0 && dy != 1.0f)
            yfrag2 = 1;

        for(xt = 0, x=0;x<dwidth;x++, xt+= dx)
        {
            xi = (int) xt;
            yi = (int) yt;
            xfrag = (float) ceil(xt) - xt;
            if(xfrag == 0)
                xfrag = 1;
            xfrag2 = xt+dx - (float) floor(xt+dx);
            if(xfrag2 == 0 && dx != 1.0f)
                xfrag2 = 1;
            red = xfrag * yfrag * src[(yi*swidth+xi)*4];
            green =  xfrag * yfrag * src[(yi*swidth+xi)*4+1];
            blue =   xfrag * yfrag * src[(yi*swidth+xi)*4+2];
            alpha =  xfrag * yfrag * src[(yi*swidth+xi)*4+3];

            for(i=0; xi + i + 1 < xt+dx-1; i++)
            {
                red += yfrag * src[(yi*swidth+xi+i+1)*4];
                green += yfrag * src[(yi*swidth+xi+i+1)*4+1];
                blue += yfrag * src[(yi*swidth+xi+i+1)*4+2];
                alpha += yfrag * src[(yi*swidth+xi+i+1)*4+3];
            }

            red += xfrag2 * yfrag * src[(yi*swidth+xi+i+1)*4];
            green += xfrag2 * yfrag * src[(yi*swidth+xi+i+1)*4+1];
            blue += xfrag2 * yfrag * src[(yi*swidth+xi+i+1)*4+2];
            alpha += xfrag2 * yfrag * src[(yi*swidth+xi+i+1)*4+3];
            for(i=0; yi+i+1 < yt +dy-1 && yi + i+1 < sheight;i++)
            {
                red += xfrag * src[((yi+i+1)*swidth+xi)*4];
                green += xfrag * src[((yi+i+1)*swidth+xi)*4+1];
                blue += xfrag * src[((yi+i+1)*swidth+xi)*4+2];
                alpha += xfrag * src[((yi+i+1)*swidth+xi)*4+3];

                for (ii = 0; xi + ii + 1 < xt + dx - 1 && xi + ii + 1 < swidth; ii++)
                {
                    red += src[((yi+i+1)*swidth+xi+ii+1)*4];
                    green += src[((yi+i+1)*swidth+xi+ii+1)*4+1];
                    blue += src[((yi+i+1)*swidth+xi+ii+1)*4+2];
                    alpha += src[((yi+i+1)*swidth+xi+ii+1)*4+3];
                }

                red += xfrag2 * src[((yi+i+1)*swidth+xi+ii+1)*4];
                green += xfrag2 * src[((yi+i+1)*swidth+xi+ii+1)*4+1];
                blue += xfrag2 * src[((yi+i+1)*swidth+xi+ii+1)*4+2];
                alpha += xfrag2 * src[((yi+i+1)*swidth+xi+ii+1)*4+3];
            }

            if (yi + i + 1 < sheight)
            {
                red += xfrag * yfrag2 * src[((yi + i + 1)*swidth + xi) * 4];
                green += xfrag * yfrag2 * src[((yi + i + 1)*swidth + xi) * 4 + 1];
                blue += xfrag * yfrag2 * src[((yi + i + 1)*swidth + xi) * 4 + 2];
                alpha += xfrag * yfrag2 * src[((yi + i + 1)*swidth + xi) * 4 + 3];

                for (ii = 0; xi + ii + 1 < xt + dx - 1 && xi + ii + 1 < swidth; ii++)
                {
                    red += yfrag2 * src[((yi + i + 1)*swidth + xi + ii + 1) * 4];
                    green += yfrag2 * src[((yi + i + 1)*swidth + xi + ii + 1) * 4 + 1];
                    blue += yfrag2 * src[((yi + i + 1)*swidth + xi + ii + 1) * 4 + 2];
                    alpha += yfrag2 * src[((yi + i + 1)*swidth + xi + ii + 1) * 4 + 3];
                }
            }

            if (yi + i + 1 < sheight && x + xi + 1 < swidth)
            {
                red += xfrag2 * yfrag2 * src[((yi + i + 1)*swidth + xi + ii + 1) * 4];
                green += xfrag2 * yfrag2 * src[((yi + i + 1)*swidth + xi + ii + 1) * 4 + 1];
                blue += xfrag2 * yfrag2 * src[((yi + i + 1)*swidth + xi + ii + 1) * 4 + 2];
                alpha += xfrag2 * yfrag2 * src[((yi + i + 1)*swidth + xi + ii + 1) * 4 + 3];
            }
            red /= dx * dy;
            green /= dx * dy;
            blue /= dx * dy;
            alpha /= dx * dy;
            red = clamp(red, 0, 255);
            green = clamp(green, 0, 255);
            blue = clamp(blue, 0, 255);
            alpha = clamp(alpha, 0, 255);

            dest[(y*dwidth+x)*4] = (unsigned char) red;
            dest[(y*dwidth+x)*4+1] = (unsigned char) green;
            dest[(y*dwidth+x)*4+2] = (unsigned char) blue;
            dest[(y*dwidth+x)*4+3] = (unsigned char) alpha;
        }
    }
}
```

I suspect my downscaling algorithm (sprshrink) works (because it is someone elses! :D), and suspect that I am blundering with my usage of pointers in testScale()! What do you think ? Am I allocating and using my pointers properly? What am I doing wrong?

Images:

Clear:

[image: Clear picture]

Artefacts when running testScale() instead of testCopy() (comment out testCopy).
[image: Artifcats after running the scaling method!]

Comment: What about a screenshot of the artifact so that we are talking about the same thing. *"I cannot use smart pointers because Texture2D requires the raw pointer!"* - I don't see how access to a raw pointer at some point inhibits use of a smart pointer.

Comment: @IInspectable As I mentioned earlier, I am inexperienced with using pointers, so perhaps I just don't understand how to do that. Righto! Pictures coming up.... but you really can't miss it if you run both methods one at a time... I will add pics.....

Comment: You are expecting users to run Mac OS X, just to see the effect. That certainly limits the potential audience, as well as the usefulness of the question itself.

Comment: @IInspectable unfortunately this is the best I can do, as I am coding on a mac! Hopefully some day I will be a better programmer and ask the perfect question for the biggest possible audience.... :)

Comment: Probably related: [Is floating point math broken?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/588004/1889329)

Comment: @IInspectable omg I so cwazy... but  if that is the case it should show in memory ? Does that mean my blundering was not with my pointer allocation deallocation !?

Comment: I agree with @IInspectable, the problem is with all the floating point going on in `sprshrink`. Every once in a while, roundoff errors might result in skipping over a destination pixel. It's better to do pixel address math as integers because it's more predictable.

Comment: @MarkRansom jajajaj I guess back to the drawing board!! But just curious ? Am I actually using pointers correct ? I'm totes faking it bros.... never had a lesson...

Comment: I haven't actually looked at the entire wall of code, but I don't see any pointer problems in the bits that I did look at.

Comment: @MarkRansom Just in testScale, scaleImage and testCopy ? I mean its really fundamental, but I have no one I ask whether I'm doing it correctly. Can you tell me? They're really small functions and it would totes make my day!

Comment: @IInspectable Sir - would you say my pointerquette in testCopy and testScale are kosher ?

Comment: Again, nothing wrong with the bits I see, but I have two suggestions. First, become familiar with `std::unique_ptr` because it saves you from having to remember to `delete`. Second, don't even use pointers here! Instead of `Image* img = new Image();` you can simply do `Image img;`. When you need a pointer to pass to a function, just use `&img`.

Comment: @MarkRansom You are right sir. I hate pointers like the black plague! But Texture2D->initWithImage() takes an Image* as input. Doesn't that mean I can't use std::unique_ptr ? (I haven't used smart pointers before, so perhaps I just don't understand)

Comment: [`std::unique_ptr`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/unique_ptr) has a `get()` member function to return the pointer to the managed object. In case you need to transfer ownership, use `release()` instead. And smart pointers aren't just a convenience here, too. They are **mandatory** to make the code exception safe.

Comment: @IInspectable Thanks you sir! I shall now read up about std::unique_ptr and try to totes amaze balls into my app! I also did not know that about exceptions... But again just out of curiosity ? did i make any coding blunders (leak / corruption) in my test methods ? I have no experienced programmer to tell me if i did totes amaze balls or not...

Comment: I haven't looked at the code. If you want to find out, run some static code analysis tools over it. Or run the application under a memory tracker (like [Valgrind](http://valgrind.org/)). Or simply make your code safer by using the [GSL](https://github.com/Microsoft/GSL), in particular the [`span`](https://github.com/Microsoft/GSL/blob/master/gsl/span) type.